# Windows 10 Calculator Key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, calculator

My keyboard has a "calculator" key on it.  In the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\18
```

I have `ShellExecute` set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedCrunch\SpeedCrunch.exe`.

*While* `regedit` is <strike>open</strike> focused, pressing the calculator key opens up SpeedCrunch, but at any other time the key opens up Windows 10's calculator app.

How can I set it to open SpeedCrunch at all times with my calculator key?

Answer (score 4):

Try surrounding the path to SpeedCrunch in quotation marks ("):

1. Create a new [registration file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#.REG_files) with a text editor and save as `keyboard_calc_to_speedcrunch.reg`:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\18]
   "ShellExecute"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SpeedCrunch\\speedcrunch.exe\""
   ```
2. [Import/merge](https://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/import-registry-file/) `keyboard_calc_to_speedcrunch.reg` into the registry.
3. Refresh Windows Explorer (using [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)): [`nircmd.exe shellrefresh`](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/shellrefresh.html)

---

To restore the original behaviour, create and merge `keyboard_calc_restore.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\18]
"ShellExecute"=-
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using AutoHotKey for this action.

http://ahkscript.org/

https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

sample:

;Winkey+C-- you can cutomise as per your need even the special keys

```
 #C::
    IfWinExist SpeedCrunch
       WinActivate
  else
     Run C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedCrunch\SpeedCrunch.exe
return
```